# Need to optimize mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb query and already created all required indices. But query still scanning all the documents in the collection.

Following is the query:

```
[
    {
        "$group": {
            "driverStatuses": {
                "$addToSet": "$driverStatus"
            },
            "batchAddedAt": {
                "$first": "$batchAddedAt"
            },
            "cityId": {
                "$first": "$operationRegion"
            },
            "pickLat": {
                "$first": "$pickLat"
            },
            "pickLng": {
                "$first": "$pickLng"
            },
            "_id": "$batchId"
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "batchAddedAt": {
                "$gte": 1705319256
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "driverStatuses": {
                "$nin": [
                    "COMPLETED",
                    "CANCELLED",
                    "START_PICKUP",
                    "ACCEPTED",
                    "WAITING"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "_id": 1
        }
    }
]
```

And it's logs is:

```
{
  "t": {
    "$date": "2024-01-16T11:47:41.418+00:00"
  },
  "s": "I",
  "c": "COMMAND",
  "id": 51803,
  "ctx": "conn486616",
  "msg": "Slow query",
  "attr": {
    "type": "command",
    "ns": "dms.batchAssignmentActivity",
    "command": {
      "aggregate": "batchAssignmentActivity",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "driverStatuses": {
              "$addToSet": "$driverStatus"
            },
            "batchAddedAt": {
              "$first": "$batchAddedAt"
            },
            "cityId": {
              "$first": "$operationRegion"
            },
            "pickLat": {
              "$first": "$pickLat"
            },
            "pickLng": {
              "$first": "$pickLng"
            },
            "_id": "$batchId"
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            "batchAddedAt": {
              "$gte": 1705319256
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$match": {
            "driverStatuses": {
              "$nin": [
                "COMPLETED",
                "CANCELLED",
                "START_PICKUP",
                "ACCEPTED",
                "WAITING"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "$sort": {
            "_id": 1
          }
        }
      ],
      "cursor": {},
      "lsid": {
        "id": {
          "$uuid": "a1ecf292-f2a0-4ce9-8520-a66f86fd3a80"
        }
      },
      "$clusterTime": {
        "clusterTime": {
          "$timestamp": {
            "t": 1705405656,
            "i": 32
          }
        },
        "signature": {
          "hash": {
            "$binary": {
              "base64": "JyBotKPMVXqaekfqPtz6E4RwE20=",
              "subType": "0"
            }
          },
          "keyId": 7278270623686590000
        }
      },
      "$db": "dms",
      "$readPreference": {
        "mode": "primary"
      }
    },
    "planSummary": "COLLSCAN",
    "keysExamined": 0,
    "docsExamined": 276938,
    "hasSortStage": true,
    "cursorExhausted": true,
    "numYields": 367,
    "nreturned": 15,
    "queryHash": "09C9423E",
    "queryFramework": "sbe",
    "reslen": 2963,
    "locks": {
      "FeatureCompatibilityVersion": {
        "acquireCount": {
          "r": 369
        }
      },
      "Global": {
        "acquireCount": {
          "r": 369
        }
      },
      "Mutex": {
        "acquireCount": {
          "r": 2
        }
      }
    },
    "readConcern": {
      "level": "local",
      "provenance": "implicitDefault"
    },
    "writeConcern": {
      "w": 1,
      "wtimeout": 0,
      "provenance": "customDefault"
    },
    "storage": {
      "data": {
        "bytesRead": 203982595,
        "timeReadingMicros": 54403
      }
    },
    "remote": "10.20.194.26:60606",
    "protocol": "op_msg",
    "durationMillis": 4453
  }
}
```

I really don't the reason. Why indices are not used here?

Sharing indices details in the screenshot.[image: Indices details]

I have already created indices but still scanning all documents of a collection. It's expected that the query should use indices.

Comment: Your `$group` looks ambiguous to me. Your `batchAddedAt` seems to work with timestamps and you do not sort them beforehand but just to pick the first entry. Also, see if you can just do `$first` in the `$group` to use the [optimization for $group](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#-group-performance-optimizations)

Comment: Please show some sample input documents

Answer (score 1):

For aggregations, indexes are only used for the first stages of the pipeline (e.g. `$match`, `$sort`). For the aggregation in question, the first stage is a `$group` stage which is a blocking stage. This means that all the documents have to be known before the pipeline can continue. This leads to the slow query that does not use an index.

Without knowing the document structure and the goal of the query, it is hard to provide a solution. So please adapt the following sample to your needs.

An important guideline from the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#indexes) is that indexes can be used in the first stages of the pipeline if those are `$match`, `$sort`, and maybe `$group`.

In your sample, you could apply a `$match` at the beginning, before grouping the documents by `batchId` (I have omitted several properties for brevity, but this should give you an idea):

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      batchAddedAt: { $gte: 1705319256 },
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$batchId",
      driverStatuses: {
        $addToSet: "$driverStatus",
      },
      batchAddedAt: {
        $first: "$batchAddedAt",
      },
      cityId: { $first: "$operationRegion" },
    },
  },
  {
    $match: {
      driverStatuses: {
        $nin: [
          "COMPLETED",
          "CANCELLED",
          "START_PICKUP",
          "ACCEPTED",
          "WAITING",
        ],
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: { _id: 1 }
  }
]
```

This can be supported by the index `batchAddedAt_1`. Due to the `$match` at the beginning, the amount of documents that is pushed through the pipeline is reduced. Please adapt the sample as needed.

Answer (score 1):

***One BIG note** about your aggregation pipeline: You're using **`$group` without having a `$sort` stage** before that. So `$first` could refer to any document. If you want `$first` to mean oldest or newest, then put a `sort` stage before that or use the [`$min`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/) / [`$max`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/) accumulators in the `group` fields.*

The two `$match` stages occur *after* the `$group` stage. So they are effectively on *computed* fields. Your indexes would only work if you were filtering on existing document fields which are covered by the indexes.

Now, a **`group + match` is not the same as a `match + group`** since `match`ing before would restrict which documents are in the `group` stage. So merely flipping the order for better performance or index usage **may not give you the desired results**.

For example, you have `"batchAddedAt": { "$first": "$batchAddedAt" }` before *some `batchId`'s* get excluded in the `match` stage with `"batchAddedAt": { "$gte": 1705319256 }`. Which means only batches which had *NO `addedAt` on or after `1705319256` get excluded*. Similarly, with `"driverStatuses": { "$addToSet": "$driverStatus" }`, you would have the `driverStatuses` even for records before `1705319256` since it was added to the set before de-selecting the latest record.

An example with these four documents:

```js
[
  { _id: 1, batchId: 100, batchAddedAt: 1705319255, driverStatus: "hello ONE" },
  { _id: 2, batchId: 100, batchAddedAt: 1705319257, driverStatus: "hello TWO" },
  { _id: 3, batchId: 200, batchAddedAt: 1705319230, driverStatus: "other ONE" },
  { _id: 4, batchId: 200, batchAddedAt: 1705319240, driverStatus: "other TWO" }
]
```

Using a [similar aggregation pipeline in mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ixas3AjtE9l):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "batchAddedAt": { "$max": "$batchAddedAt" },
      "driverStatuses": { "$addToSet": "$driverStatus" },
      "_id": "$batchId"
    }
  },
  { "$match": { "batchAddedAt": { "$gte": 1705319256 } } }
])
```

The result is:

```js
{
  "_id": 100,
  "batchAddedAt": 1.705319257e+09,
  "driverStatuses": ["hello ONE", "hello TWO"]
}
```

Notice that **both the Statuses** for batchId = 100 are in the results, even though the record with `_id = 1` is less than `1705319256`. Since doc `_id = 2` has `batchAddedAt = 1705319257` which is greater than `1705319256`, so the `addToSet` includes all the results for that batch. But both docs for batchId = 200 are excluded since both have `batchAddedAt < 1705319256`.

**Conclusion:**

So putting the `{ "$match": { "batchAddedAt": { "$gte": 1705319256 } } }` stage before `group` MAY OR MAY NOT have the desired results for you:

- Do you only want documents which have a `batchAddedAt >= 1705319256`? [match before group]
- Or do you want documents belonging to *any batch which had some `batchAddedAt` entry* >= 1705319256? [group before match]

Same goes for `"driverStatuses": { "$nin": [ "COMPLETED", ...] }`:

- Do you only want to exclude any document which has those statuses? [match before group]
- Or do you want the aggregation to exclude any batch which has those statuses? [group before match]

You can even do `match1 → group → match2` if that suits your needs or `match1+2 → group`. Or do it as `group → match1+2` if all grouping is needed before matching.

The decision should first be "which results do I want" and only after having the **correct results** should you optimise with indexes, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

looking you query mongo first is scanning and grouping all documents and hen making the filters, instead that you can make the filters at the top of the query and then the group statement. like:

```
[
    {
        "$match": {
            "batchAddedAt": {
                "$gte": 1705319256
            },
            "driverStatuses": {
                "$nin": [
                    "COMPLETED",
                    "CANCELLED",
                    "START_PICKUP",
                    "ACCEPTED",
                    "WAITING"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "driverStatuses": {
                "$addToSet": "$driverStatus"
            },
            "batchAddedAt": {
                "$first": "$batchAddedAt"
            },
            "cityId": {
                "$first": "$operationRegion"
            },
            "pickLat": {
                "$first": "$pickLat"
            },
            "pickLng": {
                "$first": "$pickLng"
            },
            "_id": "$batchId"
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "_id": 1
        }
    }
]
```